# Docker add no such file or directory

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-copy

The following is my root-directory:

```
andrej:
  - docker/CodeExperiments.jar
  - docker2/Dockerfile
```

Here are the contents of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:8
ADD docker/CodeExperiments.jar docker/
RUN javac BirthDayTask.java
```

And this is the command I am running:

```
docker build -t newfile docker2
```

Which results in the following error message:

> ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder946291442/docker/CodeExperiments.jar: no such file or directory

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CodeExperiments` is located in `docker` folder while Dockerfile is located in `docker2`.

Place them both in the same folder or at least place `CodeExperiments` in a child folder of the Dockerfile and reference from there.

Answer (score 1):

When you

```
ADD docker/CodeExperiments.jar docker/
```

it is relative to the *context directory*, which is the directory named in the `docker build` command.  That means you need to pass the current directory as the directory argument to `docker build`.  By default it's looking for `Dockerfile` in that directory, so you also need a `-f` option to point at an alternate file.

Together this looks like:

```
docker build -t newfile -f docker2/Dockerfile .
```